# View Bindings not generating

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-viewbinding

I'm currently trying out the new ViewBindings but i'm not getting them to work. I'm on `Android Studio 3.6.1`. I just created a new project and added `viewBinding.enabled = true` to my modules `build.gradle`. But when I try to access the `MainActivityBinding` class, it says it cannot resolve the symbol. Autocomplete doesn't find anything resembling a binding class. I also tried with a different project using Kotlin but no success there. `AS4.0` doesn't help either. What do I need to do to generate the `ViewBinding` classes?

My `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Ensure you call `File`->`Sync Project with Gradle Files` in Android Studio to get the view binding files generated.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

I couldn't find my `ViewBinding` files until it dawned on me that the bindings were taking their names from the `XML` files ("fragment_home.xml") and not from the class ("HomeFragment.kt"). So I couldn't find them at `HomeFragmentBinding` but I found them at `FragmentHomeBinding.`

I found it helpful to think of each ViewBinding as a helper singleton that has been created as that XML file's delegate.

(Edited to removed obsolete Gradle stuff)

Comment: Thank you. The EDIT helped me. They really should name them after the activity and not the xml though. Strange choice.

Comment: Glad I could help. Thinking about it more, I think the reason is this: A Binding could exist for XML even if no fragment for it exists. But binding could not exist for a fragment unless the XML existed. Still, though, in the big picture it could be more intuitive.

Comment: @Asim I disagree, as John says, you're specifying the binding on the XML file, _not_ the other way around. Thanks John for the (not so) obvious solution!!

Comment: @jonny Yes ofc now that I've gotten used to the naming scheme, I realize that naming them after activities would be counter-productive since view binding works for every xml and not just activity or fragment ones.

Comment: How dumb I am 

Answer (score 5):

i have just changed the names of the layouts and it worked just fine

Comment: I had gone around in circles for days until I read this. So simple but so effective! Still not sure why the caches weren't getting invalidated or remade, even deleting the Build folder didn't help. But this. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was trying to bind View

added build.gradle (module)

```
buildFeatures{
 dataBinding true
 viewBinding true
}
```

previous one was

```
viewBinding{
enabled = true
}
```

Comment: "viewBinding = true" was missing altogether from my build file, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

if you have entered fragment/layout name manually, check the spelling for keyword of the layout name like "fragment", a mistake in this would generate a binding file with the same name

Comment: I had googled for a good 10 minutes before reading this. I misspelled `fragment` as `fragement`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the build features on your module Gradle file

```
android {

  buildFeatures {
      viewBinding true
  }
}
```

And make sure your are trying with the correct layout file name. You might be working on ABCFragment but it's layout could be named as small_mistake.xml
Then your BindUtil will be something like this.

```
SmallMistakeViewBinding
```

Answer (score 0):

This Answer is writed on

> 11.11.2022

in order to generate viewbinding, here is solution:

```
android {

buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

}
```

add above code inside android tag in app module.

your ex- layout files will ne be generated, whenever you create new layout, they will be seen... So it work only with new layout files..  You dont need to add layout tag in every xml...

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the layout name is correct, name may contain a typo.

Answer (score -3):

A couple of things to make sure you have done:

- Make sure you have a properly formatted layout file, with the layout tag at the top declaring your variables
- Try a gradle sync

I haven't checked, but I know currently a few members of my team have been reporting binding classes are no longer being resolved in Android studio since upgrading to 3.6, however the project still builds fine so they are actually there, could be a bug with Android studio?

Comment: `<layout>` tag is required for the data binding.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think you're thinking of the old Data Binding feature, which is different from View Binding but has a confusingly similar name.

Comment: Thanks, after a gradle sync my view bindings started generating properly again. Seems like a bug.